# How to extract the last element from a comma-delimited string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using this query:

```
sql("SELECT _location, count(1) FROM tablaTemporal group by _location order by 2 desc" )
```

I receive this output:

```
+--------------------------------+--------+
|_location                       |count(1)|
+--------------------------------+--------+
|London, United Kingdom          |15      |
|United States                   |12      |
|Bangalore, India                |8       |
|Hyderabad, India                |7       |
|Paris, France                   |6       |
|San Francisco, CA, United States|6       |
|Mountain View, CA, United States|4       |
|Pune, India                     |4       |
|Bengaluru, Karnataka, India     |3       |
+--------------------------------+--------+
```

But the result I need is:

```
+--------------------------------+--------+
|_location                       |count(1)|
+--------------------------------+--------+
|United States                   |22      |
|India                           |22      | 
|United Kingdom                  |15      |
|France                          |6       |
+--------------------------------+--------+
```

Hence, I need to use some sentence like:

```
sql("SELECT SubstringOfLocationFromCharComma(_location), count(1) FROM tablaTemporal group by _location order by 2 desc" )
```

How to extract the last element from a comma-delimited string?

Answer (score 2):

Since the name of the country is the last element after the comma, you can also do something like this:

```
df.show(false)
+--------------------------------+
|a                               |
+--------------------------------+
|Mountain View, CA, United States|
|Pune, India                     |
|Bengaluru, Karnataka, India     |
+--------------------------------+


df.withColumn("a" , split($"a", ",") ).withColumn("a" , expr("a[ size(a) -1 ] ") ).show
+--------------+
|a             |
+--------------+
| United States|
| India        |
| India        |
+--------------+
```

This will be followed by a `groupBy($"a").agg(sum($"count(1)").as("count"))` to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_extract`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  "London, United Kingdom", "Bengaluru, Karnataka, India"
).toDF("_location")

df.select(regexp_extract($"_location", ".*,([^,]*)$", 1).alias("country")).show

// +---------------+
// |        country|
// +---------------+
// | United Kingdom|
// |          India|
// +---------------+
```

Comment: There's this saying that when you've got a problem and use regex to solve it, you'd immediately have two problems :) What's wrong with the good ol' `split` function?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Isn't that what poor devs say?  But other than being verbose, `split` + `length` + `getItem` is just not flexible enough and with even small deviation, becomes useless or turns into `case ... when` hell. Not to mention `split` is already a regexp solution.

Comment: Not working properly
StackOverflow.scala:106: value $ is not a member of StringContext
[error]       val df2 = df.select(regexp_extract($"_location", ".*,([^,]*)$", 1).alias("locationSplitted"))
maybe because i'm working with sbt

Comment: Because you didn't have implicit conversions in scope https://stackoverflow.com/q/44209756/8371915