# intelliJ running spark: cannot resolve symbol & identifier expected but string literal found & ';' expected but ')' found

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea

everyone, 
I have questions about running *spark* via *intelliJ IDEA*. If someone can offer me a help, I will very appreciate it. Thank you so much. I googled them, I tried, but changes nothing or even made the result worse, so I just keep it the original.

I have typed some easy *scala* code to test *spark* running via *intelliJ IDEA*, but some errors came out. My questions are here:

**1. Please have a look of the pic 1 & 2. There is 2 errors "cannot
    resolve symbol ===" and "value '$' is not a member of StringConext",
    and the details is in the pic 3.**

**2. If I comment the wrong code lines with "//", then the code can run, the df can be read and shown, but the code line for calculting the mean value deosn't work. Errors are shown in the pic 4 & 5.**

Could anyone please help me to resolve these 2 problems. Thank you so much!!!

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlIkW.png)

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keNbi.png)

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdilP.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwvZu.png)

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8JtO.png)

**Here is my code of pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache</id>
            <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Here is my code of scala case object**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .getOrCreate()

    val peopleDFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("sep", "\t")
      .option("header", "false")
      .load("C:\\Users\\shell\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\marks.csv")
    peopleDFCsv.printSchema()

    peopleDFCsv.show(15)


    val df = spark.read.option("inferScheme", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:\\Users\\shell\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\marks.csv")
    df.show()
    df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()).show
    df.join(df.groupBy("max(marks)"), $"marks" === $"max(marks)", "leftsemi").show
    df.join(df.filter("subject = maths").groupBy("max(marks)"). $"marks" === $"max(marks)", "leftsemi").show
    df.join(df.filter("subject = maths").select(mean(df("marks")))).show

    //    val a = new File("./data").listFiles()
    //    a.foreach(file => println(file.getPath))
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“value $ is not a member of StringContext” - Missing Scala plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209756/value-is-not-a-member-of-stringcontext-missing-scala-plugin)

Comment: thanks for your remind, but I tried it before, it doesn't work at all, the problems are still those, so I asked it here.

Comment: @MJfortruth: for your error2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652665/java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-ha

Comment: hi, I also tried this before, I'm using win10, so I set the path on "advanced system setting", I also imported the hadoop on intelliJ, but still the same error : ( "ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path"

Comment: Do I need to put the winutils into "dependencies"?

Comment: @MJfortruth: Did you actually download the winutils.exe and place it in the bin folder as described in the linked answers?

Answer (score 0):

So, first reason of error on join function is wrong arguments. In your first join function `groupBy` will return `RelationalGroupedDataset` witch is not `Dataframe`. You need aggregate something after `groupBy` function. Look at my example. For using `$` in column names you need to `import spark.implicits._`. Also, you need `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` for using standard spark column functions, look:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.io.File
val df = spark.read.option("inferScheme", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:\\Users\\shell\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\marks.csv")
df.show()
//  df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()).show
df.join(df.groupBy("column_for_group").agg(max("marks")), $"marks" === max($"marks"), "leftsemi").show
df.join(df.filter("subject = maths").groupBy("column_for_group").agg(max("marks")), $"marks" === max($"marks"), "leftsemi").show
df.join(df.filter("subject = maths").select(mean(df("marks")))).show

val a = new File("./data").listFiles()
a.foreach(file => println(file.getPath))
```

Error with winutils can be resolved setting correct environment variables. You need to google something like `windows 10 how set environment variable`. Better to do it in system, not programmatically.