# why to_date is working in Databricks but not in Intellij?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

My code is

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date

val df2=df1.withColumn("Order Date",to_date($"Order Date","dd-MMM-yy"))
```

> Error - Cannot resolve overloaded method 'to_date'

The same code is working fine in Databricks notebook.

Comment: You need to add  `import spark.implicits._` to use `$` for columns

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now it says - Value '$' is not a member of StringContext

Comment: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209756/value-is-not-a-member-of-stringcontext-missing-scala-plugin/44210165)